# Laminas: Different Layout Files for each Module

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework3, zend-framework-mvc, laminas

i would like to use a different layout file for each module which is set under `view_manager`- `template_map`in the `module.config.php`

But for some reason both modules are always using the same Layout File. Is it not possible to use different layout files for each module ?

Answer (score 0):

I have not worked on this question since ZF2 (2014) but at the time I wrote a module to answer your question. It is published on github at: https://github.com/dafap/DafapLayout
It will have to be adapted to Laminas (ZF3). To do this, replace the namespaces and edit the DafapLayout\Service\ConfigServiceFactory by replacing the createService() methods with __invoke().
Be careful, this module is in PSR0. Be sure to specify it in your composer.json otherwise it will not work.